# React Django Google Sign In

Tags: reactjs, django

I am trying to implement google sign in my Django rest react application. This is my front-end function that gets the access token and then sends it to the backend.

```
const gLogin = useGoogleLogin({
      onSuccess: tokenResponse => {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/google/signin/', {token: tokenResponse.access_token})
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Successfully logged in');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('failed to login');
        })
      },
    });
```

This is my backend code for verifying the access token and then getting the user details from google.

```
@csrf_exempt
def google_signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        token = data.get('token')
        print(token)
        if token is None:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Token is missing.'}, status=400)

        try:
            idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
                token, requests.Request(), settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
            )
            
            email = idinfo['email']
            print(email)
            user = authenticate(request, email=email)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return JsonResponse({'success': True})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'User does not exist.'}, status=404)
        except ValueError:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid token.'}, status=400)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method.'}, status=405)
```

This is the error in the backend.

Making request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

Starting new HTTPS connection (1): [www.googleapis.com:443](http://www.googleapis.com:443)

https://www.googleapis.com:443 "GET /oauth2/v1/certs HTTP/1.1" 200 1577

Bad Request: /api/auth/google/signin/

Bad Request: /api/auth/google/signin/

HTTP 400 response started for ['127.0.0.

I tried reworking the code many times but no use. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue. According to Google Docs, http://127.0.0.1:port is not valid for security reasons. For development servers, the only accepted HTTP request is http://localhost:port.

so try this change

```
const gLogin = useGoogleLogin({
      onSuccess: tokenResponse => {
        //changed to localhost
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/google/signin/', {token: tokenResponse.access_token})
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Successfully logged in');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('failed to login');
        })
      },
    });
```

To resolve this, I needed to make some additional configurations in my settings.py file:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

After implementing these changes, everything started working for me.